# Does CosmosDB replication guarantee order across containers and physical partitions?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-replication, eventual-consistency

With `Strong` to `Constant Prefix` consistency levels, they guarantee reads will never see out-of-order writes.

The below questions are particularly of interest with a multi-region + multi-master setup; if this makes a difference to the answer, I would be interested to understand what/why those differences are.

**Is order maintained across multiple Physical Partitions?**

For example with:

```
Partition1/InsertRow [val 1]
Partition1/InsertRow [val 2]
Partition2/InsertRow [val 3]
```

Is it possible that data could be made available for reading in the order:

```
[val 1]
[val 3]
[val 2]
```

**In a similar example, is order maintained across multiple Containers?**

*There are two reasons I'm unsure.*

- *With Cosmos Triggers, the order of changes can only be guaranteed within each physical partition.*
- *Containers "serve as the logical units of distribution" [Global data distribution - under the hood](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/global-dist-under-the-hood)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a multi-master account, readers in different regions where writes are made to a single region will get consistent prefix. When writes are in different regions, readers will get eventual consistency.

This is all documented here [Consistency Levels in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels).

Comment: Thanks Mark, my question wasn't really about regions though (see bold). I think your link has answered my question though: "Read consistency applies to a single read operation scoped within a logical partition. The read operation can be issued by a remote client or a stored procedure." So no, order is not guaranteed across partitions, or therefore by containers either.

Comment: Yes, correct. Order across partitions makes no sense in this type of database given partitions are functionally different VM's (compute).